# Error: The variable "System::ErrorDescription" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope

Tags: ssis

I have created a SSIS package for migrating data from one sql server database to another. The tasks are created in a sequence container. 
I have created events in the event handler and added the send mail task for sending email and getting the following error. I get this error even when I try to evaluate the expression in the expression builder. Please note that I am getting the error on the onTaskFailed event handler. I think the system error variables are not accessible in that event. Do I really need that event handler

[image]

I can see the variable in the collection. Not sure of how the scope affects it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a scoping issue. The system variable 'ErrorDescription' is only avialable at 'OnError' event handler and can't be used in 'TaskFailed' event handler. As to the question of if you need it or not, that is something your business logic should dictate. I would suggest to move your code to 'OnError' event handler.